# Android wear app not installing for samsung phones

Tags: wear-os

I have developed an android wear app. I have created signed app from android studio. Everything works fine when I use Huawei watch and LG/ Nexus/ Xiaomi phones. The apk when installed on phone automatically installs on watch.

However when I am using samsung galaxy s7 with samsung gear its not working.

Watch app does not get installed.

Comment: Unless the watch is a Gear Live, it's not running Android Wear.